# ActiveAdmin path links_to rendering raw html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

While on the Dashboard, I'm trying to hyperlink data points to their Edit page using the following code

```
DataPoint.limit(15).order("created_at desc").map do |post|
                        li link_to(post.data_type.study.name.to_s, admin_studies_path(post))
                            if post.numerical_value.present?
                                div "Number: " + link_to(post.numerical_value.to_s, admin_data_point_path(post))
                            end
```

However what happens is the raw html is rendered on the page, even though I tried adding *.htmlsafe* after the link_to(). Below's a screenshot. Any help would be much appreciated thanks. 
[image: raw html displayed]

Comment: Try adding `.html_safe`

Comment: I tried "link_to(post.numerical_value.to_s, admin_data_point_path(post)).html_safe" and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div ("Number: " + link_to(post.numerical_value.to_s, admin_data_point_path(post))).html_safe
```